# postgres regex query to match multiple strings pattern

Tags: regex, postgresql

A postgres query  selects the `elements` which have a `name` column containing **any** strings from an array:

```
select "elements".* from "elements" where "elements"."name" ~* 'hap|bir'
```

This works well.

Now, 
what is the regex pattern to select the elements only if the column contains **every** strings of the array (in no particular order)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query produces the same result as the following non-regex `LIKE` expression using an array

```
SELECT * 
  FROM elements 
WHERE lower(name) LIKE ANY(ARRAY['%hap%', '%bir%']);
```

So, to  select from elements only if the column contains every strings of the array, you change it from `ANY` to `ALL`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM elements 
WHERE lower(name) LIKE ALL(ARRAY['%hap%', '%bir%']);
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c8a25ccb733c079213302fd9297a7406)

Comment: nope, it's not actually equivalent to pass two regexps to each string in the set than to pass only one.  Regexp matching in a database is difficult to implement when you allow head wilcard expressions (you need a partial match search index, and you have to pass it through all the regexps in the array, making the search sequential, and used n times, when you have an array of different regexps)  A single regexp decides in just one pass through the search string, and as such, is more efficient than having n regexps to match.

Comment: @LuisColorado : Pardon my ignorance. I couldn't understand clearly what you are saying. If you have an answer feel free to put one.Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, you have said _Your query is **actually equivalent** to the following non-regex LIKE expression using an array_, and it is not.  Both queries require passing over the data trying to match a string (the candidate string) through a regexp matcher, but you feed your regexp in one array of n-regex, and the question uses only one.  there's a n-to-1 pass difference between both queries.  To be exactly equal, you need to construct a single regex that matches the ones in your array, and that's what the `|` operator does in normal regex.  I dont write an answer...

Comment: ... because this is not an answer to the original question.   Should I have an answer to the original question, I had written one.

Comment: @LuisColorado : Ah! ok. When I meant equivalent, I said it gives the same results. I didn't worry about the implementation part of it.  I don't know how Postgres implements the first query, so I can't say anything about it if it does in n pass or 1 pass.

Comment: @LuisColorado do you mean the regex version of the query is more efficient?

Comment: It depends on how is the LIKE operator implemented and optimised.  A good optimiser can construct a conbined automaton, optimised to make profit of a special index in the table.  This is not possible with regexp, but if not optimised this way, having to match two regexps is heavier than to match only one.  That was the reason to argue that both sentences are not equivalent.

Comment: @FrançoisRomain : You're welcome. From what I've known, queries that use basic  expressions such as `LIKE` are comparatively faster than Regexp operations .For the problem solved by the first query, I don't know if using a `LIKE` with an array is faster or not, because it depends on how Postgres implements it.Solution that I gave you to your problem of matching all regexps is the only one I know and you are welcome to explore any other efficient ones. All I would say is that If at all you find my answer helpful, consider upvoting or accepting it so that it will help everyone. Thanks!

Comment: @KaushikNayak sure. I upvoted. I am still curious to know if there is a regex for that.

Comment: How do you extract several strings? I want to extract a list of words if that row contains them.  Your answer is just to check if those words exist or not, but I want to extract them and make a column of those words.

Answer (score 3):

Guess what, you can actually combine the regexp match operator, with `ALL` over an array.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM elements 
WHERE name ~* ALL(ARRAY['\mhap\M', '\mbir\M'])
```

This may be particularly advantageous if your search text is not a single field, but a concatenation of several fields.

(Note: `\m` is start of word, `\M` is end of word.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex pattern to select the `elements` only if the column contains every strings of the array (in no particular order):

```
select "elements".* from "elements" where "elements"."name" ~* '(?=.*?(hap))(?=.*?(bir))'
```

from [here](http://dominounlimited.blogspot.com/2007/09/using-regex-for-matching-multiple-words.html).